# Working with parameters passed via URL directly through query string via Python

Tags: python, string, parameters

Using a Python CGI script, I want to take parameters given directly via URL (the user will type in the URL directly this way) and store the data in the query string as variables.

How can I do this? How do I import the URL as a variable in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [python cgi module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html) or if you want to use a slightly more powerful backend server try a basic version of any [cherrypy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) test examples.